# Can you switch between Earth and the moon without launching and restarting again?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

After you get to the moon, can you switch back to Earth without having to either restart or launch again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, after getting to the moon, you can switch from one to another without losing or paying anything.